# Make D3js DataNode tree run faster

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I am adapting this D3 example by [Rob Schmuecker](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033).  It is a DataNode tree with a lot of nice functionalities like panning, zooming and children toggling.
I have removed all drag and drop functionality from it, since I don't need it.  Otherwise, by code is pretty much the same as in the example (for now).

I am expecting to use the node tree to be populated by hundreds, perhaps thousands of nodes. At 1000 nodes the browser freezes up a bit.  Firefox lags a lot, and I have to stop the script.  Chrome lags a bit less.

The only thing I have tried so far is to create the graph with all children nodes hidden (add to `oParent._children`, instead of to `oParent.children`).  Chrome deals with this approach quite well, but firefox fares little better.

I intend to add quite things like hover effects and parent-child associations visuals etc, so I suspect that lag might become a larger problem.

Anyone have any further recommendations or ideas on how to make the browser deal with the lag problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, except for starting with all children hidden, was to separate Data Nodes and Visual Nodes, such that the visual nodes are actually only created during runtime.